# How to add a new SharePoint alert via Web Services

Tags: sharepoint, alerts

I found the Alert Service but it only seems to have methods for Getting and Deleting.  How do I add a new alert?

Answer (score 2):

After some better searching I found this:

http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sharepoint.portalserver/browse_thread/thread/9cf658fd6791e2b8/509ead400091f673?hl=en&lnk=st&q=add+sharepoint+alert+web+services#509ead400091f673

*AFAIK there is no web service available that will allow you to add or 
edit alerts so I think you have two options.*